# How to save instances of classes like LinearLayout or Button, in onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android

If my activity has member variables that are a Button or a LinearLayout, like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout lLayout;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        lLayout = new lLayout(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            button = new Button(this);
            lLayout.addView(button);
        }
    }
 }
```

The above is just basic pseudocode, but illustrates what I want to achieve - creating a dynamic row of buttons.

What exactly should I do in the onSaveInstanceState() function so that I can save the values of lLayout and button? I.e, so that when lLayout is displayed after a configuration change, it is still a row of buttons as before. I noticed that the Bundle class does not have any methods to add classes like these to a hash map, like it does for ints or String, so is there some other way to do this?

Comment: for that you don't have to save anything when you add buttons in layout on configuration change or some other function they'll still be in the same layout. What problem are you facing in that??

Comment: If I try to use lLayout after a configuration change I get a nullPointer exception. This is because on a configuration change I do not want to allocate memory again for lLayout, I want it to retain its previous value, but it is not doing that. So I want to know how to do that for LinearLayouts like it is done for String in onSaveInstanceState()

Comment: can you share your complete code I am not able to understand what you're trying to achieve here??

Comment: I am sure you know that for Fragment class there is a way to put it's value in a Bundle, i.e using getSupportManager.putFragment(Bundle, String, Fragment). However, this only exists for a Fragment. For ints, Strings, Booleans, Chars, you may use the Bundle method Bundle.putInt() or .putBoolean() etc. Now, is there a way to do this for LinearLayout, or Button?

Comment: when you put fragment that way like adding it to a backstack and getting it back again it reloads the fragment. what you're saying that you get a null pointer on configuration change you get a null pointer that's a problem in a way you have implemented your code. because it doesn't happen like that. On configuration change android calls the oncreate and it'll reload the view whatever you've implemented pro-grammatically.

Comment: Why don't you just create a recycler view within the row a button and than change the number of rows dynamically? To achive this just keep a static list of butons

Answer (score 0):

you have to overwrite the onSavedInstanceState method

Here try this :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save whatever you want to save.

  savedInstanceState.putInt("KEYINT", 1);
  savedInstanceState.putString("SavedString", "value you want to save");
  // etc.
}

then you can either get these value inside onCreate or override onRestoreInstanceState:

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState
  int savedInt= savedInstanceState.getInt("KEYINT");
  String savedString= savedInstanceState.getString("SavedString");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know how to save values for ints and strings, I'd like to know how i can do it for Button or LinearLayout member variables.

Comment: what do you wanna save for Linearlayout and button can you explain further??

Comment: In my code I am dynamically creating a LinearLayout and so I have a member variable in my Activity for it. I would like to save the value of this LinearLayout when the configuration changes/screen rotates but I don't know how to do  it as the Bundle class does not have methods for saving classes like LinearLayout or Button, like it does for int and String.

Comment: I think there is communication gap here when you say you want to save value of Linear layout do you mean you want to save parameters of Linear Layout like width,height, padding extra or something else??